# crontab exclude specific date only

Tags: unix, ubuntu, cron

How can I write a cron that will exclude a specific date.

let say : I need to run a crontab 6pm to 9pm in every 30 min on weekends and want to exclude 10th may 2014 only.

Is It possible? How can I write this? or is any alternative for this? please suggest.

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask on [unix.se]

Answer (score 0):

Your crontab will probably have to point to a shell script that will run the command only if the date is not 10th May 2014.

In your crontab: 
`0,30 18-21 * * 6,7 /path/to/your_script.sh`

And your_script.sh could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TODAY=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
if [ "$TODAY" -ne "20140510" ]; then
  your_command_to_run
else
  exit 0
fi
```

[Reference](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/run-crontab-exclude-specific-date-746317/)